# Принцип callback функции в android

Tags: callback, android, java

Немного не могу понять как можно реализовать принцип callback функции в android.

По примеру на javascript:

```
api.getNews(function(news) {
    //Тут мы обрабатываем результат из переменной news
});
api.getOtherInfo(function(info) {
    //Тут мы обрабатываем результат из переменной info
});
```

Как подобное реализовать в java ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это называется концепция замыкания.
Подробнее в общих чертах можно почитать тут http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Answer (score 0):

на java <=7 замыканий нет. только синхронный код:

```
//Тут мы обрабатываем результат из переменной news 
News news = api.getNews();

//Тут мы обрабатываем результат из переменной info 
OtherInfo info = api.getOtherInfo();
```

Comment: Да, но если у меня в getNews() выполняется асинхронная задача ?Единственный вариант это только передавать объект с методами ?

MyAPI api = new MyAPI();
api.getNews(new MyAPICallback() {
   public void onResult(News news) {
      // и тут уже обрабатывать результат
   }
});

Но как читал в некоторых учебниках, это может плохо сказаться на памяти, если создавать каждый раз новый экземпляр класс MyAPICallback

Comment: К сожалению, это единственно возможный вариант callback'ов в Java. В Java нет функций высшего порядка, да и сами функции объектами не являются, поэтому единственный способ - создавать объект класса, в котором есть метод, обрабатывающий данные. Насчёт памяти: чтобы заметно забить память объектами-коллбэками при современных объёмях памяти, придётся создавать их тысячами. Ведь по сути эти объекты не содержат никаких данных, поэтому памяти под них будет выделяться очень мало.